# Erro de permissão ao enviar arquivo para servidor da Amazon

Tags: amazon-aws

Estou tentando enviar umas alterações de site para o servidor do cliente na amazon, só que ao fazer isso ele me retorna que não tenho permissão para fazer isso, pois o site do cliente não está em `/var/www/html` e sim em `/var/www` . O usuário que estou usando não sei se foi o cliente que criou ou se já é padrão da amazon, mas é o usuário **ubuntu**.

Eu não tenho noção de como configura/mexe com Amazon, por isso preciso de ajuda. Estou usando o `Filezilla` para transferir os arquivos via `sFTP`

Comment: usuário ubuntu é padrão para Instâncias que contém o SO ubuntu e ec2-user para outos SO. você está tentando enviar ou está editando o arquivo direto no filezila? você precisa verificar as permissões da pasta pelo terminal.

Comment: Eu clico com o botão direito no arquivo e clico em editar e abre meu editor de texto, depois só do o CTRL+S e clico para enviar e da esse erro. Como abro o terminal do Amazon e executo o comando ? Sou leigo em AWS.

Comment: você pode baixar o arquivo, editar no seu computador e enviar ou abrir o terminal no ubuntu para acessar o Amazon. Se você utiliza Windows precisará do putty para conectar, o que na minha opnião é mais trabalhoso. Se você estiver utilizando o ubuntu: abra o terminal e digite ssh: -i sua chave ubuntu@ip do servidor e navegue até a pasta do arquivo e de as devidas permissões de escrita.

Comment: Oi @AlissonAcioli, Você liberou a porta para acesso FTP no Security Group da sua instancia EC2? Caso sim, você pode criar uma nova conexão via Filezilla pelo "Gerenciador de Sites"  bastando apenas importar sua key em "configurações" -> SFTP e posteriormente configurar a conexão com o host alvo.

Comment: O ideal mesmo seria você vir a permissão da pasta /var/www/html. Você consegue verificar usando o comando "$ls -l". Por padrão na distribuição ubuntu, o proprietário deve ser o usuário www-data que possui um grupo de mesmo nome. Adicione o usuário ubuntu ao grupo www-data através do comando: "sudo addgroup ubuntu www-data". Deve resolver.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal mesmo seria você vir a permissão da pasta /var/www/html. Você consegue verificar usando o comando `"$ls -l"`. Por padrão na distribuição ubuntu, o proprietário deve ser o usuário www-data que possui um grupo de mesmo nome. Adicione o usuário ubuntu ao grupo www-data através do comando: `"sudo addgroup ubuntu www-data"`.